# Function to search for a sheet in another spreadsheet in Google Sheets Scripts

Tags: function, google-apps-script, search, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Is there any way to make a function that searches for a specific sheet name in another spreadsheet to know if it exists or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

- You can use [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)) to get the spreadsheet based on its id.
- Use [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)) which returns `null` if there is no sheet with the given name. Therefore you can directly use that to check whether a sheet exists or not.

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  const sheetNameToCheck = "Sheet3"
  const anotherSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID of another Spreadsheet");
  const sheet = anotherSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetNameToCheck);
  
  if(sheet){
    console.log(`${sheetNameToCheck} exists!`);
  }
  else{
    console.log(`${sheetNameToCheck} does not exist!`);
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Spreadsheet ID of the sheet you want to search in?
This will get you the id of the sheet you are looking for if it exists

```
function searchSpreadsheet() {

  //What is your search term
  var searchTerm = "Sheet3";

   //Where do you want to search
   var destinationSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Your destination spreadsheet id");
  var destinationSheet = destinationSpreadsheet.getSheets();

  // Search spreadsheet and log name and id 
  for (i=0; i<destinationSheet.length; i++){
    if (searchTerm == destinationSheet[i].getSheetName()){
      console.log("Sheet found. Sheet name: "+destinationSheet[i].getSheetName()+". Sheet id: "+destinationSheet[i].getSheetId())
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you don't need a for loop for that (see my answer), but new answers and different approaches are always welcome :)